# Missing post-receive.sample under hooks directory

Tags: git, git-post-receive

When looking under the current repo in my local machine under .git/hooks I am unable to find post-receive.sample. When looking at other various questions I see that this is the script in which I need to work on in order to executive something right after a git push is called. However, I am unable to find the sample file and when creating a script with the name post-receive and asking it to do something as simple as echoing hello world it does not run. The script I created named post-receive does have executable permissions.

I am running git version 1.8.5.2.

Does anyone have an idea as to why the script is not working?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realized that I was trying to run a remote hook locally. That is the reason why I was unable to run the hook.